# How to pass selected file to php script using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following form is what I use:

```
<form id="form-attachment" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="attachment" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is what I do with jQuery:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form-attachment', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    console.log('fine', data);

    var url = 'imageupload.php';

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : data,

        success : function(response) {
            console.log('success: ' + response);
        },
        complete : function(response) {
            console.log('complete: ', response);
        },
        error: function(response) { 
            console.log('error: ', response); 
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my **imageupload.php** file:

```
$response = array();
$response["c"] = isset($_FILES["attachment"]);

echo json_encode($response);
```

And this is result on console on `submit()`:

> success: {"c":false}

So, what is wrong? Why my file is not visible at all?

Comment: where you want to view the file? there is no script to upload file in server.In your php file you need to use move_uploaded_file() like php functions

Comment: Please check [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Yes, I know... I will move it later, but for now it is not there for some reason...

Comment: So, it is not possible without reloading the page?

Comment: Instead of using isset use `if($_FILES['attachment']['size'] > 0)
    {
        $response["c"]=TRUE;
    } else {
        $response["c"]=FALSE;
    }` and check

Comment: I did it, and the result is: `success: {"c":false}`.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk It's just not possible without reloading the page. The only way you can upload files through AJAX is by using an iframe, which is what the library linked by user `hmd` does. [Here's more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, as shown below..

```
$('body').on('submit', '#form-attachment', function(e) {
var data = new FormData(jQuery('#form-attachment')[0]);
 jQuery.ajax({
   type: "post",
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
   dataType: "json",
   data: data,
   success: function (r) {
    // Success Handeling
   }
  });
});
```

NOTE:- *No need to append anything as other answer suggests.*
This method shall pass all the input fields just like they would in a normal http form `POST` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

Here's the example how to send file via jQuery ajax request:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
  formData = new FormData;
  formData.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]);
  $.ajax {
    url: '/upload-url',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

In your case you should serialize form first, append serialized data to the formData object. Then get file (or files) from a file field and append it to the same formData object. And finally send the formData object via ajax.